# Oracle SOA suite 12c SSL Handshake error BPEL partner link

Tags: oracle, soa, weblogic12c, suite

I have created a composite application which is referencing another webservice deployed on the same local integrated weblogic server. I am seeing the INVALID_WSDL error with ssl handshake exception when trying to deploy the composite in JDeveloper. I am using Oracle SOA suite 12c.

Comment: Its an ssl handshake error. I get it when deploying the SCA. I have configured the client side keystore to use cacerts ,server kestore to be DemoIdentity using  Jdeveloper preferences. I have imported the server cert in cacerts. Also configured the keystore property in weblogic server startup command

Comment: @jinggoy how do I refer Oracle Doc ID 1327811.1

Answer (score 0):

Look at your soa_server.diagnostics.log, I think the INVALID_WSDL is a generic error, and you should look for more details. If you're calling a secured web service over SSL, make sure the certificates are imported to your Weblogic's Java Keystores.

Refer to Oracle Doc ID 1327811.1 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your are using a clustered environment, with separated SOA nodes.

Certificates might be imported into the first node and not the second.

Make sure that both nodes are equal.

Comment: I am using single node which is integrated in JDeveloper. The SSL handshake error goes away if I recreate the solution for BPEL process. However when I create the manual task and generate the task form the error comes back. I tried restarting the server, recreating the complete example again but the error comes back. I am using default demo keystore and demo truststore. Server is an integrated node in JDeveloper.